# Ammo lost with 2 SMGs?

Tags: just-cause-2

In Just Cause 2, My one handed weapons of choice are 2 6-star SMGs. I use one SMG, but when I run out of ammo with it, the other one is empty as well. Does it take ammo from my other SMG, or is the ammo from the other one just disappearing? If it takes ammo from it, does that mean I have twice as much ammo for 1 SMG? I've also heard that the Happy Bubble Blaster uses SMG ammo. If it does, would that be able to be used as an ammo carrier (similar to the second SMG)?

Comment: Don't have it installed so I can't check, but I *think* I remember that the ammo is not per-gun.  That is, the amount of ammo you see is simply how much SMG ammo *you're carrying*.

Comment: So having two of any weapon would be useless?

Comment: Well, you can fire them both at once, so "useless" is arguable I guess.  In terms of ammo capacity, I guess so.

Comment: Yeah, I don't dual wield. So you're positive about the ammo thing? If that's true, its kind of dumb.

Comment: No, I'm not positive, since I haven't played this game in years.  That's why I posted a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Alright. I'll see what other people have to say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have seperate clips, but take ammo from the same source.

Say you have 240 SMG ammo, and you have 40 additional shots in both SMG one and SMG two.

You can fire SMG one 40 times(SMG has 30 capacity and increases by 2 every level), then you reload and your original 240 SMG ammo is reduced to 200.

After firing SMG one 40 times **and reloading**, SMG two has the same amount in it's clip, but you have less SMG ammo.

Effictively, dual wielding doubles your DPS(Damage Per Second), ammo consumption and increases your max ammo by just 40.

Comment: Okay. Does the HBB hold SMG ammo? I think I read that somewhere. If so, would that also give me extra ammo?

Comment: HBB? not sure what that is, but having two weapons that use the same ammo will only allow you to hold one extra clip.

Comment: Happy Bubble Blaster. I've heard it uses SMG ammo. It has a large clip as well, so it would be beneficial if it works.

Comment: Ah, but the ammo it holds in the clip is limited to the gun, so yes you are holding extra SMG ammo, but it's only effective as bubble mix haha

Comment: So the HBB does not help me carry extra ammo.

Comment: No, it does not.